# Read the replied date for a mail using JavaMail API IMAP

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I am currently reading mail details via IMAP. I am able to collect all the details of Sender, subject and date received. If the mail has been replied, I need to collect the replied date as well. In the mail snapshot attached I am able to see "You replied to this message on" tag with date and time. Is it possible to get the replied date from the current mail using the JavaMail API?

[image: "You replied on" snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

That date is the Date field of a message whose References contain the Message-ID of the message you're currently looking at.

So what you need to do is store your message's message-id, then look for another message in that mailbox that's from the user and mentions that message-id in its References field, and finally you can use that other message's Date.

Comment: Which assumes you can find the reply message, probably in the "sent" folder.  Also, there's an "ANSWERED" flag that some email clients will use to mark that a reply has been sent to a message.

Comment: Indeed: If you can't find the answer you can't say "you repllied to this message".

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, nothing **requires** the reply to be stored at all, let alone stored in the same mail server as the original message.  But doing so is very common, so this heuristic is likely to work often enough to be useful.